# C, fread binary from bin file

Tags: c, binary, fread

I'm pretty new to C, but I have come across a problem with fread...

My end goal is to read (and then printf to console) the binary from a .bin file, but for now i'm taking it one step at a time and trying to just read the first bit...

My code:

```
...
FILE *file = fopen("test1.bin", rb);
int i = 0;
fread(&i, 1, 1, file);
printf("%i\n", i);
...
```

Now i've tried this on three different .bin files, one outputted 0, other 2 and the other 12!

Why is it outputting 2/12 when I am reading in just one 1 bit from file? Shouldn't it be a 0 or a 1? what am I doing wrong? Thanks alot.

Comment: You are reading 1 byte, not 1 bit. :)

Comment: Right, okay thanks so if I wanted to read just 32 bits, I would change 1, 1 to 4, 1?

Comment: Better to change to sizeof(int),1.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Change the [`fread()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/fread/) call to:

```
fread(&i, sizeof(int), 1, file);
```

The second argument is the size of an element to read, the third argument is the number of elements to read. The posted code is reading a single byte into an `int`.

You should also check the return values from `fopen()` and `fread()` calls to ensure they were successful.

Answer (score 1):

Like @hmjd said, you should read the number of bytes necessary to fill an `int` value. So either this way:

```
len = fread(&i, sizeof(int), 1, file);
```

or this way:

```
len = fread(&i, 1, sizeof(int), file);
```

The first case reads one `int` value (typically as 4 bytes). After the call, `len` should be equal to 1 if the read succeeded.

The second case reads multiple bytes into an `int` value. The difference is that after this call, `len` should be equal to `sizeof(int)`.

Either way will work, the only difference being that the first way specifies reading a multiple-byte single object (an `int`), whereas the second specifies the number of bytes to read into the object. It's a subtle difference, and people will disagree which is best, of course.

The advantage of the second method is that `len` tells you exactly how many bytes were actually read (which might be useful for debugging I/O errors). The advantage of the first method is that it's a conceptually simpler test for success (was one `int` read or not?).

But no matter how you do it, you should always check the return value of `fread()`.