# How can I read a single value at the position indicator of a file?

Tags: c, binaryfiles

So I'm supposed to read a random value from a binary file. So far my code looks like this.

```
char * filename = argv[1];
FILE * file = fopen(filename, "rb");
long int x;
x = random() % 100;
int ret = fseek(file, x, SEEK_SET);
```

So I have the position indicator of the file at the random value's position. Now how can I read only a single value from the file? I'm already at the position, I just have to read the one value thats at that position.
Also,the file has 100 random integers placed in it. It is a binary file.
Can I use the long int I have to get a random value from the file? or would I need to pass fseek something like x = x*sizeof(int)? Not really sure if I'm going to be able to get my randomg value from the binary file because Ive never worked with these files before so I dont know how my code sees it. Since it's open with the "rb" parameter, does my code read the values in base10 or does it see the binary conversions?

Comment: If the file has 100 random "integers" in it, then your random seek position must be a multiple of `sizeof(int)` - although I shudder to ask, if the file itself contains random data, who cares?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C, fread binary from bin file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10841946/c-fread-binary-from-bin-file)

Answer (score 1):

I can not comment so I am writing from here. Do you really have to read only one token or you are required to access a token by using a random number `x`?

**EDIT:**

Since you need to read a token from a file you can use:

```
char * filename = argv[1];
char buffer[2];
FILE * file = fopen(filename, "rb");
long int x;
x = random() % 100;
int ret = fseek(file, x, SEEK_SET);
fread(buffer, 1, 1, file);
```

Comment: If it is not the case you can read all the file into one array and access to it with the random number.